# How to find type of relationship between nodes in graph db?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j database in my project and I have a number of cities (nodes as A, B, C, D, E) linked with relationships "toward ->" and "backward <-" (both directions). So,  each pair of neighbor nodes (AB, BC, CD ..) has two relations and two directions resp.

```
A ->/<- B ->/<- C ->/<- D ->/<- E
```

How can i get type of relations between A and E (toward or backward) if startnode is A and endnode is E (should be "toward", but how to get it as result)?  I use next query, but it returns absolutely all relations for both directions

```
MATCH p= (n:City{name: A})-[r*]->(m:City{name:E}) return nodes(p), r
```

and it returns correct result if not typing * but only for AB, BC, CD and so on... but not for AE.

Comment: Can you share the output of your query?

Comment: If `A` and `E` are connected, just drop the `*` and use: `MATCH (n:City{name: "A"})<-[r]->(m:City{name:"E"}) RETURN r`

Comment: There is no direct relationship between A and E so your query will not return such relationship.

Comment: Thanks! As i wrote abobe, A and E are not connected. Only next nodes connected: A ->B, B->C, C->D, D->E. A and E is a path, but not relation. I need to get type of relations between A->B, B->C and so on...

Comment: output: Nodes:[A, E, D, C, B, A, E, D, C, B] r: [Toward, Toward, Toward... Backward, Backward,  Backward,  ...]